# How to read text file in dolphindb?

Tags: database, file, scanf, readfile, dolphindb

The dolphindb manual says it can read file like

```
fin = file("C:/DolphinDB/test.txt")
x=fin.readLine()
```

But `readLine()` will return a string of this row.

I have a text file like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

How can I get these nine digits one by one ?

Answer (score 0):

After you read the line, use the code below to convert

```
split(readLine(), ' ').int()
```